# how can I use the translated names of the days in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, function, date, translate

I configured my yml file and translation works fine in console. For example when I write `I18n.t('date.day_names')` i get `["domenica", "lunedì", "martedì", "mercoledì", "giovedì", "venerdì", "sabato"]` insted of ["sunday, monday....]

Now i've this function

```
 def date_of_next(day)
    date  = Date.parse(day)
    delta = date > Date.today ? 0 : 7
    date + delta
  end
```

date_of_next "Sunday" ---> returns the date of the next Sunday

how can I use this feature with my names translated?
date_of_next "Domenica"

Comment: Put `date_of_next` method in the `Date` class. Because Ruby's classes are open, it will override the predefined `date_of_next` method.

Comment: ok i understand, but where should I write the code? can you show me a pseudo-code please? thank you!

Comment: So, in whatever file you defined `date_of_next`, just wrap it with `class Date`. So you can do `class Date; def date_of_next(day); ... ; end; end;`